# STRANGE Situation -> Mysql ERROR 2002 (HY000)

Tags: mysql

I've created subdomain that ate up all the RAM and made Mysql display `ERROR 2002 (HY000)`, so I deleted the subdomain and the process it was creating no longer ran. ok, so I restart mysql, reboot server, and still `ERROR 2002 (HY000)`.

I see `mysql.sock` in `/tmp/` so I edit `/etc/my.cnf` to use `mysql.sock` from there. Also `/emp/mysql.sock` is present. Also added bind-address to the `/etc/my.cnf` to `127.0.0.1`. Now the only way I can access mysql is running.

> mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306 -u root -p

This shows the tables are ok, which was my concern. Now I'd like to backup the tables and re-install mysql (since I've already spent too much time on it  or if you guys know some better solution). mysqldump dosen't work for the same reason, I've tried this cmd:

> mysqldump -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306 -u root -p --host [my_db] > my_db.sql

But the `.slq` (opening in Sublime) shows only some instructions and no data.

What to do?!!

Im desperate.

Comment: Is there data in your tables?

Comment: What are the instructions, its probably the error returned from your mysqldump command, which might give you an idea of how to fix it.I think it should be `mysqldump -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306 -u root -p [my_db] > my_db.sql`

Comment: yes there is data @ceejayoz and the instructions are not useful, just usage stuff: Usage: mysqldump [OPTIONS] database [tables]
OR     mysqldump [OPTIONS] --databases [OPTIONS] DB1 [DB2 DB3...]
OR     mysqldump [OPTIONS] --all-databases [OPTIONS]
For more options, use mysqldump --help

Comment: I've also tried to dump all of the tables, but .sql returned is the same.

Comment: Anybody? Please any ideas help.