# Dump mysql databases from mysql console? (Impossible the normal way)

Tags: mysql

For a number of reasons describe here:

[STRANGE Situation -> Mysql ERROR 2002 (HY000)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29152974/strange-situation-mysql-error-2002-hy000)

I cannot use mysqldump. Is there another program or way to dump dbs through the mysql console? The only way I can get into the console is running

mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306 -u root -p
(due to problems stated above - or if I re-install mysql, which could be risky)

Hope someone help us save our data!

Comment: Did you say `mysqldump -h 127.0.0.1 -u root -p` (etc)

Comment: I've tried all variations of mysqldump, it needs to be some other way. Maybe backing up the fdata older itself /var/lib/mysql ? is a strategy like this recommended? http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/40390/reinstall-mysql-but-keep-database-tables-and-data

Answer (score 0):

for the future, the SOLUTION:

mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306 -u root -p -e "show databases;" | tr -d "| "

mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306 -u root -p -e "show databases;" \
 | tr -d "| "  \
 | egrep -v "(Database|mysql|information_schema)"

for db in \
   `mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306 -u root -p -e "show databases;" \
   | tr -d "| "  \
   | egrep -v "(Database|mysql|information_schema)"`; \
   do  mysqldump -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306 -u root -p --opt --routines --databases $db   "$db.sql"; done

I received this error in one of the databasese, but it hasn't affected my production ones, so Im cool with it.

mysqldump: Got error: 1142: SELECT,LOCK TABL command denied to user 'root'@'localhost' for table 'cond_instances' when using LOCK TABLES

Credits to:

http://vitobotta.com/smarter-faster-backups-restores-mysql-databases-with-mysqldump/